# wavesurfer tag (<wavesurfer>) does not work

Tags: javascript, html, wavesurfer.js

I want to use wavesurfer.js and use the `<wavesurfer>` tag, but I do not know how and whatever I do, the sound does not load.

```html
<wavesurfer
  data-url="http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/post/audio/4095c5f534c74f10951da8259772b549.mp3"
  data-plugins="minimap,timeline"
  data-minimap-height="30"
  data-minimap-wave-color="#ddd"
  data-minimap-progress-color="#999"
  data-timeline-font-size="13px"
  data-timeline-container="#timeline"
></wavesurfer>
<div id="timeline"></div>
```

where is the problem?

Comment: I can't see any reference to a `<wavesurfer>` element [in the documentation](https://wavesurfer-js.org/docs/). Where is that coming from?

Comment: @Andy it's [here](https://wavesurfer-js.org/example/html-init/index.html) but I'm guessing they're missing some important parts

Comment: From [this issue](https://github.com/katspaugh/wavesurfer.js/issues/701) it sounds like you might simply be missing something like `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wavesurfer.js/6.2.0/wavesurfer.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score -1):

If you are using react then you will have to install dependency of 'wavesurfer-react' using

```
npm install wavesurfer-react
```

You can import it in you jsx file using

```
import {WaveForm, WaveSurfer} from "wavesurfer-react";
```

Now WaveSurfer tag will be accessible in your code.
Hope this helps!

Comment: I don't see any indication that they are using react.